# Dexter + Goa'Uld = Extra Sadistic + Extra Evil

Tags: society, aliens, evil

I'm thinking of building a world by mixing two existing worlds: Dexter and Stargate SG-1.

In Dexter, the main character is an evil psychopath/sociopath (note: I'm still not 100% what the difference is, but it is immaterial to this question).

In Stargate SG-1 (at the beginning), the villains are the Goa'Uld who inhabit and control the bodies of helpless humans who are then forced to watch [almost] forever while their bodies are used to commit horrible atrocities.

It's well-known that the Goa'Uld are able to relinquish control to their hosts - but why would they? They're bent on world domination.

Until, of course, they inhabit Dexter, thereby creating host and symbioses each as sadistic as the other.

With the power of two equally sadistic minds working 100% in tandem, the resultant entity would be almost entirely unpredictable.

Societies today, during warfare, attempt to draw distinct lines between the self and the enemy because that allows you to write them off as "not-self" and therefore not worthy of the protections you would otherwise afford the self. When the lines become blurred, when you can no longer determine if an act was that of a human committing a crime or an enemy committing an act of war, you ability to fight diminishes. We, to some extent, see this with the war on terror because the "enemy" is much less defined than it usually is.

What would be the societal impact of the combination of *the self* (humans/Dexter) and *the other* (the Goa'Uld)?

Comment: [Here's](http://www.webmd.com/mental-health/features/sociopath-psychopath-difference) an article just to help clarify the difference. :)

Comment: You know, you're story can go two routes. Number one is a weird fan fiction mash up of an animated TV show and a SciFi movie about alien parasites. The other option would be to make it more origional, have your own parasitic race and an evil scientist of your invention. Just saying.

Comment: This question is out of scope for Worldbuilding, I think. Partly idea generation (but that rule is frequently broken over here), partly actions of a specific fictional character.

Comment: So you're essentially boosting a psychopath inclination to "evil" through aliens means. Why would the society react any differently than if he was that evil to start with? If they know about goa'uld, they'll fight them as in SG1. And if they realise that one of their victims is behaving badly, he'll be treated as such. Once by the army, the second time by the police.

Answer (score 2):

This can't happen. Even though the  Goa'Uld can access their host's thoughts, they hardly care ... They are not the TokRa. They have no interest in the "human, for anything but their vessel like functions. GIven I've never seen dexter, I highly doubt he'd gladly destroy the entire Earth just for amusement and fun, unlike our lizard friends.

A Goa'Uld has never been known to share host, this is due to the Sarcophagus taking away anything human-like from them, caused by thousands of years of use. The only time a human can influence a Goa'Uld is when the later is severely hurt (Apofis' son on the Earth attack) We even see Teal'c's girlfriend trying to influence her  symbiot, and later Teal'c trying himself to no avail. Both fail miserably and those were young undeveloped symbiots.

TLDR The very idea of sharing is way way beneath the Goa'Uld. They are GODS the greatest creatures to ever roam the Universe, not some car buddies.

Answer (score 1):

Dexter is not evil. In his opinion the things he does are justified and he cannot act if his victims do not fit his [Code](http://dexter.wikia.com/wiki/The_Code_of_Harry) (Especially interesting are those few occasions in which he knows that some person has to die because they did or will do something evil but he can't act until he finds something fitting the Code)

As such Dexter is in no way compatible with a Goa'Uld and they certainly would not form some kind of symbiosis. Dexters evilness might be partially selfish(his desire to kill) but also bound to a somewhat moral set of Rules, while the Goa'Uld truly only care about themselves and nothing/no one else.

Now if we ignore all of that and just assume a Goa'Uld is pairing up with Dexter as his host it would probably make this entity less evil than normal Goa'Uld but also most likely a lot better at fighting SG-1 since Dexter is pretty good at killing humans.

Answer (score 1):

**Not much**

Goa'Uld do not have any influence from the host - something seen several times in the series. The trial of Skara and his Goa'Uld is the one that initially springs to mind - Skara had a device hung around his neck which suppressed the Goa'Uld and forced it to allow Skara to talk. Indeed, the unwillingness for the Goa'Uld to listen to their hosts was a recurring theme on the series.

If, however, we assume that the Goa'Uld for some reason does undertake a true symbiotic relationship with the host similar to the Tok'Ra, then even with the additional sociopathic tendencies of Dexter (as in Dexter the Serial Killer of the Dexter TV series and the Darkly Dreaming Dexter book series, not Dexter-the-Scientist of Dexter's Lab) with none of the "brakes" Dexter has put in place, we have very little change in the overall attitude of the Goa'Uld.

Additionally, this is a race who have a genetic memory, and can remember the crimes of their race. Indeed, they often revel in it, fully enjoying the whole **"I AM A GOD. *KNEEEL* MORTAL!"** scenery chewing hammy nature of their race.

This is a race who are happy to enslave whole populations, genetically modify a race of humanity to become living incubators for their young, and who have created numerous technologically ingeniously nasty torture devices. A single lifetime's sociopathy pales in comparison with ***Millenia*** of genocidal, torturing behaviour.